# Instance of class inside of the class itself

Tags: c#, oop, instance

This code works:

```
class Person{
    public Person p;
    public string name;
    private int age;

}
class Solution {


    static void Main(String[] args) {

        Person z = new Person () { name = "Stacl"};
        Console.WriteLine (z.name);
        Person a = new Person ();
        Console.WriteLine (a.name);

    }
}
```

But this doesn't work:

```
class Person{
    public Person p = new Person (){name = "Inside",age = 45}; // add 'new'
    public string name;
    private int age;

}
class Solution {


    static void Main(String[] args) {

        Person z = new Person () { name = "Stacl"};
        Console.WriteLine (z.name);
        Person a = new Person ();
        Console.WriteLine (a.name);

    }
}
```

Can you explain to me how and why this happens?

Comment: This leads to a stack overflow.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski good point, but what if the type is not `Person` but `Foo` by example then u can't do this as well right?

Comment: @DarkBee sure you can

Comment: @Person.Junkie What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: "Don't work" is not a valid problem description. Explain what happens.

Comment: @CodeCaster problem is stack overflow

Comment: @dav_i he's a Person junkie...

Comment: @Person.Junkie You should include that kind of information in your question.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski yeah you're right. Just tested this. Well usualy i just write an init function to set properties like that

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @Lucas mentions in comments, this causes an infinite loop of creation of `Person`.

You can not construct a `Person` without initializing the `p` field, which constructs a `Person`, which constructs a `Person`, etc...

Which of course, eventually results in a `StackOverflowException`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are actually trying to achieve is this:

```
class Person{
    public string name = "Inside";
    private int age  = 45;
}
```

Creating a Person instance within a Person instance will result in a StackOverflowException.
But since you are accessing the 'name'-field rather 'p'-field from outside, it is not necessary anyway.

By the way, you should replace your public fields with properties, because this is a recommended style.

```
class Person{
    public Person() {
        Name = "Inside";
    }

    public string Name {get; set;}
    private int age = 45;
}
```